# load data within iframe returned from spring controller

Tags: html, jsp, spring-mvc, iframe

I want to load/show the data inside an IFrame. I'm calling the spring controller through iframe and in spring controller i have logic to get the data from database which i need to print/show within iframe. Below is the code i tried but data is not printed within IFrame, please suggest.

showData.jsp

```
<iframe src="/showData.htm" width="900" width="100%" style="border:1;" id="iframeId" scrolling="yes" ><c:out value="${data}"/></iframe>
```

spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/showData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getMasterReleaseData(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            BindingResult beException)
    throws IOException {

try{
 //code to get the data from database
    String data = dto.getData();
    mav.setViewName("showData");
    mav.addObject("data",data);
                    }
catch(Exception e){
}
return mav;
}
```

Comment: Did you try opening showData.htm in a normal page first (as in accessing the url on a browser)? Also, try moving <c:out value="${data}"/> inside showData.jsp.